# Continuing IE8 -> IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I have to modify an application in order to work on IE11. Now I find the comboboxes *weird looking*

I do not know what to do to fix them.

[image]

The combobox code:

```
<select name="Trimestre">
    <option value="Q1">Q1
    <option value="Q2">Q2
    <option value="Q3">Q3
    <option value="Q4">Q4
</select>

SELECT {
    z-index:1
    font-family: Arial, verdana; 
    font-size:8pt;
    color:#0060A0; 
    background-color:#C2EFFF; 
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: groove #C2EFFF 10px; 
    border-right: groove #C2EFFF 2px;
    border-left: ridge #FEFEFE 2px; 
    padding-right:2px; 
    padding-left:2px; 
    padding-bottom:20px;
}
```

Comment: I'm here to learn, if you downvote without telling why, I won't learn and repeat my mistakes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT {
    padding-bottom: 6px;
}
```

Try reducing the pixels of the padding on the bottom. 
Is the drop down giving the list of items?

Comment: thanks, thats it. why in IE8 doesnt matter and IE11 does?

Comment: You welcome... To answer your question it might have to do with CSS3 (Cascading Style Sheets). Different browsers are compatible with different features. Maybe go through this article. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508(v=vs.85).aspx    Hope it helps

Comment: hahah the funny thing is that the code is meant for IE8 but nothing happens ... maybe thats why the 20 px value

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
padding-bottom: 20px;
```

Just change or remove it.

And you have this:

```
border-bottom: 10px groove #c2efff;
```

Reduce or remove it.